# Upload multiple Image with preview without using Submit Button

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I am trying to create a product upload form in which I have to upload multiple images and show previews. So far I can upload image when using submit button...How to make it work without using submit button. This my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-l4wj6q) demo code.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input 
            formControlName="name"
            id="name" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control">
        <div *ngIf="f.name.touched && f.name.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="f.name.errors.required">Name is required.</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.name.errors.minlength">Name should be 3 character.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="file">File</label>
        <input 
            formControlName="file"
            id="file" 
            type="file" 
            class="form-control"
            multiple="" 
            (change)="onFileChange($event)">
        <div *ngIf="f.file.touched && f.file.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="f.file.errors.required">File is required.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <img *ngFor='let url of images'  [src]="url" height="150" width="200px" style="margin: 3px;"> <br/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
onFileChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (event:any) => {
                  console.log(event.target.result);
                   this.images.push(event.target.result); 
                   this.myForm.patchValue({
                      fileSource: this.images
                   });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a way you can call it inside change event at the end of if statement. Then every change you can upload files without clicking button.

```
onFileChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (event:any) => {
                  console.log(event.target.result);
                   this.images.push(event.target.result); 
                   this.myForm.patchValue({
                      fileSource: this.images
                   });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
        }
    this.submit();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I fell so stupid.. Just add like that...Thank you so much brother...